# How to pass parameters through this.props.history.push()

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react and redux to build my app
I have a input field in my TopNav (Nav Bar) and i have to perform search operation

```
         <input
            placeholder="Search"
            type="text"
            id="searchTerm"
            onChange={this.search}
          />
```

My search method is

```
searchAsset = event => {
    console.log(`Search for this ${event.target.value}`);
    const searchValue = event.target.value;
    if (searchValue.trim().length > 2) {
      this.props.history.push(`/company/library?q=${searchValue}`);
    }
  };
```

And in my library.js page

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { q } = this.props.match.params;
    console.log(q);
  }
```

But my query is still empty
My url is changing but this.props.match.params is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

query params are not available in `match.params` but `location.search` whic you then will have to parse. You can use `queryString` library to do that

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { q } = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
    console.log(q);
  }
```

or parse it with javascript

```
 componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const  params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search)
    console.log(params.get('q'));
 }
```

Comment: which approach is more efficient?

Comment: First approach is more flexbile and will be better if you have multiple such places where you want to perform the same logic. Downside is that you need to include a library which adds to your bundle. The efficiency will more or less be the same

Answer (score 1):

History push could accept an object as a first argument and you can pass argument like this:

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/company/library',
  search: `?=${searchValue}`  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ReactBrowserRouter:

```js
import {
  ... , 
  useLocation // Make sure to import this for your custom hook
} from "react-router-dom";

// You can create a custom hook
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

function QueryParamsDemo() {
  // Use your hook
  let query = useQuery();
  
  // Get the url Query parameters
  // I used 'name' in the example, in your case name should be 'q'
  let name = query.get("name");

  /*
  Your custom code here
  */
}
```

I used the example of the documentation here to explain it to you.
More information can be found at [React Browser Router Documentation - Query Parameters](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

**EDIT**
Some more useful information about React router:

> React Router does not have any opinions about how you should parse URL
> query strings.
>
> If you use simple key=value query strings and you do not need to
> support IE 11, you can use the browser's built-in URLSearchParams API.
>
> If your query strings contain array or object syntax, you'll probably
> need to bring your own query parsing function.